# Trying to display Cards using Images in WPF, why is it not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I've tried Using Images and Bitmap Images in WPF C# to dynamically change what images I am displaying in my project, it is however not working. I am not getting any errors and if I put in an incorrect Source it tells me it is wrong, but it doesn't actually display any pictures when I run the code without any errors in it. This is the C# code I am trying to run:

```
var mainwindow = new MainWindow(); //creating a link to the UI to access the image controls
Players[i].Cards = new Card[2];
Players[i].Cards[0] = Deck[i * 2];
string Suit = Convert.ToString(Players[i].Cards[0].Suit);
string Rank = Convert.ToString(Players[i].Cards[0].Rank);
Image Card = new Image();
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.UriSource = new Uri($@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Cards\{Suit}\{Rank}.png", UriKind.Relative);
source.EndInit();
Card.Source = source;
```

You can assume that the source is correct, I've already tested this.

I've tried a lot of stuff like only using Bitmap Controls and static image source, which is not what I want to use, but even that didn't work. Is there any setting I need to change to make it work? If I load the source directly into the XAML code it does work, but then I can't change it depending on the cards I get dealt. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing anything with Card? It should somehow be added to the visual tree of your application.

Comment: `var mainwindow = new MainWindow(); //creating a link to the UI to access the image controls` is a misconception. You won't create a new MainWindow, but instead access the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply initialize the `BitmapImage` directly:

```
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Cards\{Suit}\{Rank}.png"));
```

*Note: you had specified a relative type of uri, but are in fact using a full path which I left off.*

Answer (score 0):

I see several odd things but the main issue here is you're instantiating a new MainWindow rather than referencing the one which is presumably already shown.

You should instead do:

```
 var mw = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
```

Note that a wpf app has a MainWindow which is the first window which is opened as the app starts up. That could be called anything. FooWindow for example.
By default it is also called MainWindow. But the type of the main window of an application is not always MainWindow.

So what?  You need to cast it.

As I think Nate mentioned, you can use code like this to load an image:

```
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();  
    bitmap.BeginInit();  
    bitmap.UriSource = new Uri($@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Cards\{Suit}\{Rank}.png");  
    bitmap.EndInit();  
    Card.Source = bitmap;
```

Once you do that the Image control is just there in memory.

You need to add it to a window which is visible to actually see it.

```
        mw.CardsPanel.Children.Add(Card);
```

If that code is not in mainwindow, then CardsPanel must be public. By default, controls are private memvbers and you can't just reach into a window and reference those.

In MainWindow you could have:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="CardsPanel" x:FieldModifier="public">
    </StackPanel>
```

Alternatively, you could expose a public method from MainWindow which adds cards.

The usual way to approach this sort of thing in wpf would be via MVVM. If you have a collection of cards you'd define a CardViewModel with picture url, suit, rank etc and you'd bind a collection of 52 of these to an itemscontrol or listbox. Template out each CardViewModel into a CardUserControl using data templating.

Comment: Thank you so much that was rly helpful! I changed the way i referenced the window to the way you suggested and it now works!!!! thank you so much!!!!